# Rotating 3D rigidbody object (with camera as child) with mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mouse

I am rotating an 3D object with camera (as child) and a rigidbody with Mouse and keyboard. I am using the following codesnippet:

```
private void Update()
    {

        float rh = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        float rv = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
        float rx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Roll");

        rotInput = new Vector3(rv, rh, rx);
        Thrust();  //Move forward and backward

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Moving.MoveInput(rotInput);
    }
```

I can move the 3D  object (and the camera) with the mouse, but when I look to the left or to the right, the camera is slipping a little diagonal. I want to rotate with the mouse just like a FPS, but with a rigidbody (not with transform.euler....). Does anyone know a solution so that the camera moves exactly in order with the mouse (without slipping diagonal)?

I change the code to:

```
void moveWithMouse()
{
    moveCamera(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), arrowMouseSpeed);
}

void moveCamera(float horizontal, float verticle, float moveSpeed)
    {
        mouseX = horizontal;
        mouseY = -verticle;

    rotY += mouseX * moveSpeed;
    rotX += -mouseY * moveSpeed;
    roll += Input.GetAxis("Roll");
    rotInput = new Vector3(rotY, rotX, roll);
    Debug.Log("rotInput" + rotInput);

}
```

But now it keeps rotating and I can't stop it. I still use a ridigbody. Is there a solution, so the mouse works correct and the camera stop rotating when I stop moving the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a roll. That's what is tilting the camera diagonally. Set the z of `rotInput = new Vector3(rv, rh, rx);` to 0 and it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanx, but I need the roll (keys Q and E) for 6DOF. I tried with z = 0, but this don't work, I still get the tilting diagonally. I hope you can help me with this.